# Why we need Java NIO Selector?

Tags: java, nio, serversocket

If we are creating a online-chat sever, i think we should only need a single ServerSocketChannel, isn't it ?

If we get only one ServerSocketChannel, why we need a Selector ?

Could anyone gives me a real project example needs to use Selector ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `accept()` on a `ServerSocketChannel`, what you get back is a new `SocketChannel` which you then `read()` and `write()` to communicate to that client.

Your selection code would typically `select()`, then iterate through the selected keys, accepting any key that `isAcceptable()` (thus opening a new channel), but then also reading and writing any key (presumably one of your accepted client channels) that `isReadable()` or `isWritable()`.

Answer (score 0):

you need a selector to support non blocking NIO. if you use blocking NIO (which is the default) you dont need a selector.

Answer (score 0):

> If we get only one ServerSocketChannel, why we need a Selector

Because you will have lots of accepted `SocketChannels,` and a `Selector` lets you deal with them all in the same thread.